# Query in Query Also Divide in SQL

Tags: sql

```
Select  COUNT(PLAYER_CODE)/COUNT(PLAYER_CODE Where PLAYER_CODE is null)
From PLAYER
```

Not sure if my topic is right or not, but i don't know how do you do the sub query thing in sql, i want to USE the number of Player code that is not null divided player code that is null and make it to percentage.

Answer (score 3):

```
Select sum(case when PLAYER_CODE is not null then 1 else 0 end) / 
       sum(case when PLAYER_CODE is null then 1 else 0 end)
From PLAYER
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help, but can you please tell me what does "is not null then 1 else 0 end)" mean?

Comment: Outside is the `sum` which sums up whatever is inside. The `case` is a condition that returns 1 if true and 0 otherwise. The `sum` adds up these decisions.

Answer (score 0):

Select  ISNULL(COUNT(PLAYER_CODE),0)/ISNULL(COUNT(PLAYER_CODE),1)
From PLAYER

--You always use 1 in Divisor because if you use 0, you get unexpected result